# Migration of DB2 LUW V8.2.7 to SQL Server 2005 Standard Edition

Tags: sql-server-2005, db2

Is there any way to migrate a DB2 Database to SQL Server 2005 Standard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are tools available for the migration process.
Here are few links to check out Hope they help you -

http://www.ispirer.com/products/db2-to-sql-server-migration

http://www.swissql.com/products/datamigration/data-migration.html

You can also download this pdf document -

http://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache:bO3rNPhuMXkJ:download.microsoft.com/download/C/0/C/C0C8C15A-32AD-418E-85BF-A6FF0CCE052C/MigrateDB2toSQLServer_2009.pdf+migration+of+DB2+database+to+sql+server&hl=en&gl=in&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESjX8kwdSOxyeXccigtzKTg9Yb2GS1BtBQGiYlMqTjIo-lQ2uaNvt8Ppw7IpiFypl-bCNv5Mik_nwZOtArPG_9YC4jvCiHqERBM37jQKAUbim4jwdTgSx9EvS5FwZ4GHcgSg3Nwg&sig=AHIEtbRaYGRoM0of1q77PQsBVyPWnWDWKg

Comment: @andyh_ky - Thanks. altough you accepted my answer, I did not get the bounty. any idea?

Comment: @Sachin Shanbhag / mods - figured out the issue w/ the bounty. Thanks.

Comment: Ask, and ye shall receive pain.  Wait on the bounty; it will come.  However, a recent recalc of rep hit you hard.  probably because you're deleting answers like crazy.

Comment: @Will - I have been deleting answers, but I did not know it would cost me dear. Can you tell me if there is anyway I can get my reputation back?

Comment: @Sachin Not really.  Its like when the bank falsely credits you a thousand bucks.  When they take it back, you don't have much recourse in the matter.  Recalc logic is beyond my pay grade; I've lost thousands of points in recalcs (lived through some major changes in rep calc early in the site's history).  Don't sweat it too much.  Look up Jon Skeet's rep and realize how puny we mortals are.